# Abstract a subsetting pattern

Tags: r

I've been given a script to extend and have been I see this pattern a lot:

```
newdf <- df[ which(df$someCol %in% c(values...)), ]
```

After puzzling over it for a while I figured out that it subsets a dataset based on the presence of values within a column. In an effort to make the code easier to read, I wanted to abstract it into a function. Like this:

```
subset_column.vals <- function(x, col, selectors) {
   return(x[which(x$col %in% selectors),])
}
```

But the function always returns a data frame with 0 rows. Even when the expression with the same inputs outside of the function returns an expected result. Anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: such a function exists: `dplyr::filter(col %in% selectors)` for instance. Also, you are missing `,]` after selectors

Comment: Don’t use `.` in variable/function names! It’s a terrible convention from the early days of R and messes with S3 method lookup. Instead, it’s recommended to use `_` consistently everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @KonradRudolph! I've got that going throughout the script I've inherited. The person who wrote it was also a newb.

Comment: @scoa Thanks for pointing me to dplyr. The script already had it installed and uses it here and there, but not to its fullest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already functions that do this quite efficiently. For instance:

- using `dplyr` : `dplyr::filter(x,col %in% selectors)`
- in base-r : `subset(x,col %in% selectors)`

If we really want to write another one, this would work:

```
subset_column_vals <- function(x, col, selectors) {
  return(x[x[,col] %in% selectors,])
}

subset_column_vals(iris,"Species",c("setosa"))
```

Notice that we use `[` instead of `$` to subset the data.frame, because `$` does not work well with quoted arguments.